# How to open a Base64 encrypted 7z File on Windows?

Tags: encryption, window, 7-zip

As the title already describes, I have a text file with base64-code which was originally a password protection `*.7z` file.

How do I proceed correctly to get the content from this file, under Windows?

---

My attempt so far was

1. Decode Content of Text File in ASCII (with a simple Python 2.7 Script)
2. Save Output as `*.7z`
3. Try to open this File with `7-Zip`

But that did not work. If i try to open the file `7-Zip` tells me, "{Target File} is no Archive".

---

An example File

http://pastebin.com/f1Rqgs7c

Comment: Why the `downvote`?

Comment: Not my downvote, but likely because the question does not contain enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Added some working exampe File.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
certutil -decode base64encoded.7z decoded.7z
```

and then open the 7z file in 7Zip, enter the password etc. as usual.